# How to access all of the files in the selected folder?

Tags: ios, nsfilecoordinator, security-scoped-bookmarks

The user picks a folder of video clip files, which will all be sequential, and my app plans to iterate through all the files in the folder and assemble them into one complete video. This is typically on iCloud, DropBox, box or other such location.

I am using NSFileCoordinator and [NSURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource] and these make the folder itself available, but apparently not the files inside it.

Is there any way to extend the access privileges of the folder to the items within it?